# The account does not exist in this organization error during Microsoft SSO

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to do a microsoft sso, where any user can use his microsoft account to sign in to the app. Now, if the user is part of the application users it works perfectly fine, but when I try to log in with my personal one, it gives me an error message saying "The account does not exist in this organization".

My endpoint for the sso:

```
    const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000/redirect";

    const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

    const scopes = ["user.read"];

      router.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
  // Construct a request object for auth code
  const authCodeUrlParameters = {
    scopes: scopes,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
  };

  // Request auth code, then redirect
  cca
    .getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters)
    .then((response) => {
      return res.send(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => res.send(error));
});

router.get("/redirect", (req, res) => {
  // Use the auth code in redirect request to construct
  // a token request object
  const tokenRequest = {
    code: `${req.query.code}`,
    scopes: scopes,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
  };
  // Exchange the auth code for tokens
  cca
    .acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest)
    .then(async (response) => {
      res.send(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => res.status(500).send(error));
});
```

[image]

Comment: First you need to create an account.Click on the `Create One` and continue with the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

> It gives me an error message saying, "The account does not exist in this organization".

The error message shows that your personal Microsoft account is not associated with the organization that the application is using for authentication. Microsoft provides two different authentication services: Microsoft Account (MSA) and Azure Active Directory (AAD).

By using Guest method, you can use your personal account by assigning the roles.

If your organization has set up the application to use AAD for authentication, then you need to have an AAD account in the same organization in order to log in.

1. Create an AAD account and map it with the same email address as your MSA. This will allow you to log into the application using your AAD account.
2. And if you don't want to create an AAD account, you can use a different email address (such as a work email address) that is already associated with the organization's AAD.

**Steps to create Microsoft SSO**

Register your application to access Microsoft Graph API, and you need to first register your application in the Microsoft Developer Portal and obtain a client ID and secret.

The first step in the authorization code grant flow is to redirect the user to the Microsoft authorization endpoint. The user must sign in and grant the permissions that your application requests.

After the user grants permission, Microsoft will redirect the user back to your application with an authorization code.

Your application can then exchange this code for an access token by making a POST request to the Microsoft token endpoint.
Once you have an access token, you can use it to call the Microsoft Graph API on behalf of the user. To do this, you'll need to add the access token to the Authorization header of your API request.

Access tokens are short-lived and need to be refreshed after a certain time period. You can use the refresh token to obtain a new access token without requiring the user to sign in again.

```
async function getAccessToken(code) {
  const tokenRequestBody = querystring.stringify({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
  });

  const tokenResponse = await axios.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', tokenRequestBody);

  return tokenResponse.data.access_token;
}

async function getUserProfile(accessToken) {
  const userProfileResponse = await axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });

  return userProfileResponse.data;
}

async function main() {
  const code = 'AUTHORIZATION_CODE';

  const accessToken = await getAccessToken(code);
  const userProfile = await getUserProfile(accessToken);

  console.log(userProfile);
}
```

References taken from

[Nodejs-webapp-msal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal)

[ADD](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant.md)